# What physical features of the tetrahedron prevent its symmetry group from being all of $S_4$?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, symmetric-groups, polyhedra

This is an exercise from the book ["Visual Group Theory"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/088385757X) by Nathan Carter.

**Exercise $5.26$.** As you know from the chapter, the symmetry group for the tetrahedron is $A_4$. We can think of it, as you saw in **Exercise $5.25$**, as permuting four vertices. What physical features of the tetrahedron prevent its symmetry group from being all of $S_4$?

[image: tetrahedron-abcd]

Intuitively, $(A\ D)$ is not in the symmetry group for the tetrahedron. However, how to justify this more rigorously (e.g., mathematically maybe in terms of geometry)? For example, can we justify this in terms of isometry? (I am not sure.)

Comment: Um ... The transposition $(A,D)$ corresponds to reflection in the plane perpendicular to $\overline{AD}$ at its midpoint, so it's in the symmetry group.

Comment: @Blue, I think "symmetry" is being confined here to rigid motions in 3-space.

Comment: This is a bit like asking what physical features of a shoe prevent you from turning a left shoe into a right shoe.

Comment: @DerekHolt Can we justify that in terms of isometry? (I am not sure.)

Comment: There is an isometry taking a left shoe to a right shoe – reflection is an isometry. Again, I think the magic phrase is "rigid motion".

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Some people deem reflections to be "rigid motions", despite the lack of *continuous conveyance* from start to end that one might reasonably expect from the term. (Extra-dimensional rotation notwithstanding.) A cursory survey of Google results seems to favor "rigid" reflections. An [MAA activity](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/4/vol1/architecture/Math/Rigid_Motion.html) includes them; [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RigidMotion.html) does not. A safer magic phrase may be "orientation-preserving/direct isometry"; or, here, simply "rotation".